# AWS EC2 cloud-init script run as ec2-user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I am baking an image on top of Amazon linux image.
I need to run a service as ec2-user.
Is it possible to run a launch script of any kind as user other than root?

Comment: I think I saw a User Data script once that created a user, used `su` to 'become' that user, then ran some commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're going to put the command under `UserData`.

> Scripts entered as user data are executed as the root user, so do not use the sudo command in the script. Remember that any files you create will be owned by root; if you need non-root users to have file access, you should modify the permissions accordingly in the script. Also, because the script is not run interactively, you cannot include commands that require user feedback (such as yum update without the -y flag).

Here's the full [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) discussing topic

Comment: There is actually a mistake in the documentation you reference where `sudo` is used and is not necessary: `sudo systemctl enable httpd`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```bash
su ec2-user -c 'your commands go here'
```